# Warning happens in Vue.js 2 when using Vuex 4

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

The warning occured in the console when I tried to use Vuex 4 as a store in Vue 2. How can I resolve it?

> export 'inject'/ 'reactive'/ 'watch' was not found in 'vue'

[image: warnings in console]

Below are the `package.json` entries for Vue (v2.x) and Vuex (v4.x):

[image: package.json file showing Vue v^2.6.11 and Vuex v^4.0.2]

`store.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        todos: [],
        logs: []
    },
    mutations: {
        ADD_TODO(state, todo) {
            console.log('add todo work')
            state.todos.push(todo)
        },
    },
    actions: {
        addTodo({ commit }, todo) {
            commit('ADD_TODO', todo)
        }
    },
})
```

`main.js` file:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import store from './store'

Vue.use(ElementUI);
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using Vuex 4 which works with Vue 3 only. For Vue 2, you must use Vuex 3. Take a look at the note on the [official Vuex documentation](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/).